I can't open snap apps I guess
Issue Description
Hi, I'm on ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1021-oracle aarch64), I downloaded firefox with snap. when i try to open firefox with root from the command line I get this.
$ firefox
  Client is not authorized to connect to ServerError: cannot open display: :1.0

when I try with a normal user...
$ firefox
2024/05/08 19:18:26.344861 cmd_run.go:1081: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Expected portal at
 "/run/user/1001/doc", got "/home/ubuntu/.cache/doc"
/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-333.scope is not a snap cgroup

Troubleshooting Steps
the root error we know what it is the $DISPLAY variable is correct I'm just using vnc, I tried
$ xhost +SI:localuser:$USER

  localuser:root being added to access control list
  X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8

if someone have an answer to this please share.
But what burned my mind is the other one. I could not find any explanation on it online let along a solution.
$ SNAPD_DEBUG=1 snap run firefox
2024/05/08 19:30:44.831554 logger.go:93: DEBUG: restarting into "/snap/snapd/current/usr/bin/snap"
2024/05/08 19:30:44.841527 logger.go:93: DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"start", "time":"1715196644.841523"}
2024/05/08 19:30:44.847263 logger.go:93: DEBUG: executing snap-confine from /snap/snapd/21467/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
2024/05/08 19:30:44.847875 logger.go:93: DEBUG: SELinux not enabled
2024/05/08 19:30:44.848251 logger.go:93: DEBUG: creating transient scope snap.firefox.firefox
2024/05/08 19:30:44.848286 logger.go:93: DEBUG: session bus is not available: cannot find session bus
2024/05/08 19:30:44.848293 logger.go:93: DEBUG: snapd cannot track the started application
2024/05/08 19:30:44.848299 logger.go:93: DEBUG: snap refreshes will not be postponed by this process
2024/05/08 19:30:44.848306 logger.go:93: DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap to snap-confine", "time":"1715196644.848304"}
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine enter", "time":"1715196644.849810"}
DEBUG: umask reset, old umask was   02
DEBUG: security tag: snap.firefox.firefox
DEBUG: executable:   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec
DEBUG: confinement:  non-classic
DEBUG: base snap:    core22
DEBUG: ruid: 1001, euid: 0, suid: 0
DEBUG: rgid: 1001, egid: 1001, sgid: 1001
DEBUG: apparmor label on snap-confine is: /snap/snapd/21467/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
DEBUG: apparmor mode is: enforce
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine mount namespace start", "time":"1715196644.850328"}
DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1001 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/.lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1001 (change: yes)
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope (global), uid 0)
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: ensuring that snap mount directory is shared
DEBUG: unsharing snap namespace directory
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1001 (change: yes)
DEBUG: releasing lock 5
DEBUG: opened snap-update-ns executable as file descriptor 5
DEBUG: opened snap-discard-ns executable as file descriptor 6
DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1001 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/firefox.lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1001 (change: yes)
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope firefox, uid 0)
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: initializing mount namespace: firefox
DEBUG: device cgroup not required due to base core22
DEBUG: setting up device cgroup, mode "optional"
DEBUG: libudev has current tags support
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0 has matching current tag
DEBUG: get bpf object at path /sys/fs/bpf/snap/snap_firefox_firefox
DEBUG: found existing device map
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: found 20 existing entries in devices map
DEBUG: delete key for c 142:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:2
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 226:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 226:128
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 248:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 141:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:3
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:8
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 138:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 143:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:9
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 139:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 140:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 136:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:7
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 137:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 10:200
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:5
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: load program of type 0xf, 33 instructions
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:3
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:5
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:7
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:8
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:9
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:1
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:2
DEBUG: v2 allow c 136:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 137:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 138:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 139:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 140:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 141:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 142:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 143:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 10:200
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/dri/card0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 226:0
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-Virtual-1 has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-Virtual-1
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/renderD128 has matching current tag
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/dri/renderD128
DEBUG: v2 allow c 226:128
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/virtual/dma_heap/system has matching current tag
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/dma_heap/system
DEBUG: v2 allow c 248:0
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/virtual/mem/full has matching current tag
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/full
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:7
DEBUG: process in cgroup /user.slice/user-0.slice/session-333.scope
/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-333.scope is not a snap cgroup

I though I should correct the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS veriable so I did export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus" To find out later that the $XDG_RUNTIME_DI veriable returns nothing.
$ snap --version
snap    2.62
snapd   2.62
series  16
ubuntu  22.04
kernel  6.5.0-1021-oracle

Conclusion
And I tried a few other things I found online, but I don't remember them.
So I gave up and decided to try another browser, to find out that what ever I download with snap gets the same result.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1951491 sounds like you may have tried some of the suggestions in this very long thread already!

yes already have...

I have had a similar issue where firefox in a VirtualBox system. It just doesn't want to start. I get that error saying that display :0 is not available.
In my case, rebooting once has worked every time. It's not ideal, but everything I've seen never worked. I am thinking that it is in a weird state and just thinks that the display is not available (at least for a snap project).
